# Dynamically add HyperLink in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I have two types of code:
1st:

```
               <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text="Скачать объект" NavigateUrl='<%#"objects/" + Eval("Идентификатор") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                    </ItemTemplate>    
                </asp:TemplateField>
               </Columns>
```

works normal. But TemplateField showed everytime.

2nd

```
            TemplateField templField = new TemplateField();
            HyperLink hypLink = new HyperLink();
            hypLink.NavigateUrl = "<%#\"objects/\" + Eval(\"Идентификатор\") %>";
            hypLink.Text = "Скачать объект";
            templField.InsertItemTemplate = (ITemplate)hypLink;
            tableResults.Columns.Add(templField);
```

dosn't work with error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink' to type 'System.Web.UI.ITemplate'. Why in 1st time HyperLink added, in 2nd time didn't?

Comment: Could you please describe your requirement to achieve using gridview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help to get started:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    { 
        var hyperlinkField = new TemplateField();
        hyperlinkField.ItemTemplate = new HyperlinkColumn();
        tableResults.Columns.Add(linkField);
    }
}


class HyperlinkColumn : ITemplate
{
    public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
    {
        HyperLink hypLink = new HyperLink()
        container.Controls.Add(link);
    }
}
```

Note that you cannot set the `NavigateUrl` or `Text` from within `InstantiateIn`. There you only create the control. You would databind it in `RowDataBound` according to the row's `DataItem`.

**But**:

> Although you can dynamically add fields to a data-bound control, it is
>   **strongly recommended** that fields be statically declared and then shown
>   or hidden, as appropriate. Statically declaring all your fields
>   reduces the size of the view state for the parent data-bound control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.templatefield.aspx

Comment: You just have to change the `Visible` property of that column. For example: `tableResults.Columns[0].Visible=false;` if you want to hide the first column.

Answer (score 0):

`templField.InsertItemTemplate` expects an `ITemplate` object where as hyperlink does not extends this interface.

In your first declarative example, hyperlink is a host of `ItemTemplate` which extend this interface `ITemplate`.