# Dynamically create item template hyperlink field in gridview ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to dynamically create a template field which has an item template consisting of a hyperlink field. Trying to recreate the below code in the backend asp.net code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total" SortExpression="TotalCases" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign ="Center" ControlStyle-ForeColor="Black">
                           <ItemTemplate>
                              <asp:HyperLink ID="TotalCases" Target="_blank" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TotalCases") %>' />
                           </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

I have created a new template field called totalcases and now I am trying to get the item template as a hyperlink field which is where I am getting stuck

```
TemplateField TotalCases = new TemplateField();
            TotalCases.HeaderText = "Total";
            TotalCases.SortExpression = "TotalCases";
            TotalCases.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            TotalCases.ControlStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            TotalCases.ItemTemplate = new HyperLink(); //THIS DOESNT WORK
            clientgv.Columns.Add(TotalCases);
```

Error: cannot convert type System.Web.UI.WebControls.Hyperlink to System.Web.UI.Template. An explicit conversion exists.

I am trying to get the hyperlink URL assigned in the rowdatabound method but it cant find the hyperlink and is coming back as null on debug

```
 HyperLink hltc = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("TotalCases");
```

Comment: How do you put the hyperlink field inside the item template?

Comment: why would you want to do this? It would be much easier to hide the existing column then to add one programatically.

Comment: I need it to be done dynamically as it loops through a sql code and generates gridview based on the number of rows in the output. I dont want this hardcoded i want it dynamically done in the back end code. Its my requirements.The existing column will then be removed once I have figured out how to dynamically create it in the back end

Comment: `class HyperlinkColumn : ITemplate{    public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)    {        HyperLink hypLink = new yperLink();        container.Controls.Add(link);    }}` Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288215/dynamically-add-hyperlink-in-gridview

Comment: Dont think i get it. In the example they add 'link' what is link? Its not defined anywhere

Comment: @roa765 `link` is mostly likely `hypLink`, just a typo probably

Comment: How do i assign  Text='<%# Eval("TotalCases") %>' to the Item template?

Comment: you need to access Hyperlink on ItelmTemplate and then assign new hyperlink TotalCases.ItemTemplate.HyperLink = new HyperLink();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look on the below code.

```
TemplateField customField = new TemplateField();
customField.ItemTemplate = new GridViewTemplate(DataControlRowType.DataRow, "FirstName", ControlType.HyperLink);
customField.HeaderTemplate = new GridViewTemplate(DataControlRowType.Header, "First Name", ControlType.Label);
gv.Columns.Add(customField);


 public class GridViewTemplate : ITemplate
    {
        private DataControlRowType templateType;
        private ControlType controlType;
        private string columnName;

        public GridViewTemplate(DataControlRowType type, string colname, ControlType contType)
        {
            templateType = type;
            columnName = colname;
            controlType = contType;
        }

        public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
        {
            switch (templateType)
            {
                case DataControlRowType.Header:
                    Literal lc = new Literal();
                    lc.Text = "<b>" + columnName + "</b>";
                    container.Controls.Add(lc);
                    break;
                case DataControlRowType.DataRow:
                    WebControl firstName = null;
                    switch (controlType)
                    {
                        case ControlType.Label:
                            firstName = new Label();
                            break;
                        case ControlType.HyperLink:
                            firstName = new HyperLink();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    firstName.DataBinding += new EventHandler(this.FirstName_DataBinding);
                    container.Controls.Add(firstName);
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void FirstName_DataBinding(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow row = null;
            switch (controlType)
            {
                case ControlType.Label:
                    Label l = (Label)sender;
                    row = (GridViewRow)l.NamingContainer;
                    l.Text = DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, "FirstName").ToString();
                    break;
                case ControlType.HyperLink:
                    HyperLink l2 = (HyperLink)sender;
                    row = (GridViewRow)l2.NamingContainer;
                    l2.Text = DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, "FirstName").ToString();
                    l2.NavigateUrl = "https://www.google.com";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    public enum ControlType
    {
        Label = 1,
        HyperLink = 2
    }
```